# How to get Map values and create String type for each of them

Tags: android, dictionary

I have a `Map<String, String> values` which returns me key-pair values, I want each values as a string.

For example output should be like :

```
String a = "map value 1"
String b = "map value 2"
```

How do I make it, should I use iterator, if yes then how can I get each values in String?

Output :

```
11-30 14:05:03.344 21403-21403/com.example D/getActionValue: Map Values are : {com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_ID=-1638692152, com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_PAYLOAD={"attribution":"Campaign Name Group"}, value={"hasLoyaltyId":"please enter name"}, com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE={"subject":"Title","message":"Notification Message","notification-action":{"name":"go to screen","value":{"hasLoyaltyId":"please enter name"},"type":"gotoscreen"}}}
```

After 1st level Iteration, i am still not getting values, coz it contains multiple values within which you can see in output

```
11-30 16:19:36.998 9429-9429/com.teleca.sam.engine D/getActionValue: Attribution is : Campaign Name 30
11-30 16:19:36.998 9429-9429/com.teleca.sam.engine D/getActionValue: Map Values are : {com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_ID=1671068670, com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_PAYLOAD={"attribution":"Campaign Name 30"}, value={"hasLoyaltyId":"please enter name "}, com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE={"subject":"Title 1","message":"Notification Message 1","notification-action":{"name":"go to screen","value":{"hasLoyaltyId":"please enter name "},"type":"gotoscreen"}}}
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: key : com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_ID
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: value : + value
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: key : com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE_PAYLOAD
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: value : + value
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: key : value
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: value : + value
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: key : com.ibm.mce.sdk.NOTIF_SOURCE
11-30 16:19:36.999 9429-9429/com.example D/getActionValue: value : + value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can as follow,

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : hashmap.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Object value = e.getValue();
        String a=e.getKey()+" "+e.getValue();
        Log.e("Map",a);
    }
```

Comment: I got that, I made changes, I have another worry here. The value also contains multiple values within, which I again need to iterate?? Let me put output in question

Comment: yes, you need to iterate again as follows
JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject(e.getKey());

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = menu.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = menu.getString(key);
        map.put(key,value);
    }

Answer (score 2):

You could just iterate through the Map. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) for `entrySet` states:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map.

So based on that, you can use it in your iterator to do what you want.

```
Iterator it = values.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) 
{
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
}
```